# google chart pass segment value

Tags: javascript, donut-chart

I am trying to figure out how to pass value from segment from google donut chart through javascript. Following this [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) (the donut one), I modified html like: `onmouseover="segmentMouseOver(event)"`
to pass the event onMouseOver. Although, I cannot find a way to pass the value of donut's segment, on which is mouse over.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));    

function selectHandler() {
  var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
  if (selectedItem) {
    var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
    alert('The user selected ' + topping);
  }
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler); 
chart.draw(data, options);
```

you can find out more [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_interactivity).

Comment: It works pretty good with `click="selectHandler()"` but If I want to take the value onmouseover, I am getting: http://imgur.com/a/ePQJX